# Adding scroll if the data is very long in autocomplete textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have implemented a functionality for `autocomplete multiselect textbox` and it works very well.

So now my issue here is, If I have 3000 records and I type **A** in the textbox, a very long list of values starts appearing in the list.

Have a look at the below screenshot.

[image: Img]

So, is there any way to reduce by adding scroll to the list. Below is my complete set of code.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt712" runat="server" Width="80%"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        SearchText();
    });
    function SearchText() {
        $("#txt712").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Frm_Agreement_Master.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'username':'" + extractLast(request.term) + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            },
            focus: function () {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var terms = split(this.value);
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push(ui.item.value);
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push("");
                this.value = terms.join(", ");
                return false;
            }
        });
        $("#txt712").bind("keydown", function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        function split(val) {
            return val.split(/,\s*/);
        }
        function extractLast(term) {
            return split(term).pop();
        }
    }
```

**CS**

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string username)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    using (OracleConnection ObjPriCon = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ToString()))
    {
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT DISTINCT survey_area_7_12 FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_farming_mst WHERE survey_area_7_12 LIKE '%' || :searchtext || '%'", ObjPriCon))
        {
            ObjPriCon.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":searchtext", username);
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(dr["SURVEY_AREA_7_12"].ToString());
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know how to add `Scroll` so that it doesn't gets Overlapped

Comment: Inspect the parent div of the list and in css give it a fixed `height` and `overflow:hidden`

Comment: @karan3112: I don't have `div` as such, here is my html: `<td class="field" style="width: 30%;">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt712" runat="server" Width="80%"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>`

Comment: try this css `.ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 600px;
    overflow-y: auto;   /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* add padding to account for vertical scrollbar */
    z-index:1000 !important;
}`

Comment: @shantaram: its confusable in the comment. post this an answer. I am not able to view what to add,

Comment: @nad Ideally the autocomplete list will have a parent `div` or `ul` which is added dynamically from js. Inspect the class and add the css.

Comment: @shantaram: Your answer didn't worked for me. But still I upvoted for your first comment. Also, I am free to chose to mark answer for which I want. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With JQuery UI autocomplete, you can do like [this](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#maxheight):

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: it is working for me, can we change the font of the list as per our style. Let me know from where we can do that..

Comment: I got that too. Thanks a lot Quentin for your quick help

Comment: you welcome :)
To change the font, you can do like this:
    .ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item {
          font-size: 14px;
          font-family: fantasy;
     }

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-autocomplete { 
    max-height: 600px; 
    overflow-y: auto; 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    z-index:100 !important; 
}
```

**change searched text style as**

```
.ui-autocomplete.ui-widget {
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif; //any font 
    font-size: 10px;
}
```